# What happens to integration over a term that converges to zero in probability?

Tags: convergence, asymptotics

I have to do integration like this $\int h(x) [\hat{g}_n(x) - g(x)] dx$ ,where $\hat{g}_n(x)$ is a non-parametric  estimator of $g(x)$ and $\hat{g}_n(x) - g(x) = o_p(1)$; $h(x)$ is an arbitrary function of x that is bounded , i.e., $\int \mid h(x)\mid\,dx < \infty$. Is  $\int h(x) [\hat{g}_n(x) - g(x)] dx =o_p(1)$ as well?

Comment: Do you need to prove convergence for _all_ bounded $h(x)$, or you can _choose_ a specific bounded $h(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\hat{g}_n(x) - g(x) = o_p(1)$ pointwise, then no. The other answer gave one counterexample. Another is to let the support of $x$ be $[0,1]$, $h(x) = 1$, $g(x)=0$, $\hat{g}_n(x) = n 1\{x \in [1/n,2/n]\}$.

If $\hat{g}_n(x) - g(x) = o_p(1)$ uniformly in $x$, meaning that $\sup_x |\hat{g}_n(x) - g(x) | = o_p(1)$, then yes. 
$$ \int h(x) [\hat{g}_n(x) - g(x)] dx \leq \int |h(x)|dx \sup_x |\hat{g}_n(x) - g(x)| < C o_p(1) = o_p(1)$$

Comment: More generally you'd require that $\|g_n(x)-g(x) \|_\infty=o_p(1)$.

Answer (score 2):

No I don't think so. Take $g_n(x)=g(x)+z_n(x)$ where $z_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ for $x\leq 1/n$ and 0 otherwise, with uniform measure on $[0,1]$. Then:

$P(|g_n(x)-g(x)|>\epsilon)\leq 1/n,$

meaning that $g_n(x)-g(x)=o_p(1)$.

On the other hand, take $h(x)=1/\sqrt{x}$. Then:

$$\int_0^1 h(x)z_n(x)dx=\infty$$